# Flash Player и своя программа

Tags: c#, flash

Всем привет!
Меня интересует такая вещь: Как можно взаимодействовать с Flash Player'ом, то есть воспроизвести в нем какой то Flash файл и отобразить его у себя в программе?

Comment: Говорят не сложно.
Через ActiveX объект.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/635085/Playing-Flash-Files-SWF-in-Csharp-Form

делал когда то, но давно было, не знаю как сейчас с этим в WPF приложениях, в .net forms без проблем

Comment: @ShockWave, Мне как раз и нужно под форточки

Comment: Да и в WPF несложно. Например, [через WebBrower](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7631091/276994), [встраивание контента WinForms в WPF](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/janiv/2009/09/20/embedding-and-communicating-with-the-macromedia-flash-player-in-wpf/) (вот [ещё ссылка](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx)).

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы и за оперативность

Comment: @VladD, а ещё можно видеоплеер встроить :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Способ

Через компонент браузера webBrowser

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://site.com");   // страница сайта с флеш-содержимым
webBrowser1.Navigate("C:\\file.swf");      // локальный флеш-файл
```

---

## 2. Способ

Через COM компонент Shockwave Flash Object

```
axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, "http://site.com/flash.swf");   // флеш-объект в сети
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = @"C:\holdthelinegame.swf";           // локальный файл
```

(!) Флеш-объект в сети обязательно должен быть прямой ссылкой на .swf файл.
Узнать прямую ссылку можно покопавшись в исходном тексте страницы сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]